# laravel $request->input() doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to retrieve a single input from laravel request

```
$request->input('username')
```

But it returns undefined in `ajax` response, I tried:

```
$request->only('username')
```

as well as:

```
$request->username`
```

but none of them work, exept for:

```
$request->all()
```

which returns the right data object:

```
Object {
    username: "username",
    password: "password",
    _token: "uKi2r3G1XPiOLhi13da3NC67ssjc1qmeiGWFtQNM"
}
```

So I need to access single values.

Comment: can you show ajax code.

Comment: $request_data = $request->all(); $user_name = $request_data['username'];

Comment: the issue is not with ajax coz I log in laravel but it gives me empty string : `Log::info($request['username']);` gives this in laravel.log : `[2016-09-20 12:50:06] local.INFO:   ` nothing

Comment: How is `$request` defined in your code?

Comment: here is how I'm able to access single value - `$request['data']['username']` but it is still weird , laravel docs don't mention this syntax at all

Comment: request is an array

Comment: this is how I define request : `public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {   
     Log::info($request['data']['username']);
     }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$request['username'];
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Try to print your request in log and check that you are getting values or not. Or if possible share your code.

Comment: `Log::info($request['username']);` gives this in laravel.log : ` [2016-09-20 12:50:06] local.INFO: `  - empty

Comment: It means you are not getting 'username' param with your request. First check that you are getting all parameters in your request. Just use Log::info($request) and check that which parameters you are getting in request

Comment: here is `Log::info($request)` result  `[2016-09-20 15:39:10] local.INFO: array (
  'data' => 
  array (
    'username' => 'blabla',
    'password' => 'blabla',
    '_token' => 'JChRU2chhtTlcmLA2aml9Q3q0AZPF8n7xx4UtKls',
  ),
)`

Comment: here is how I'm able to access single value - `$request['data']['username']` but it is still weird , laravel docs don't mention this syntax at all

Comment: It is correct. If you are sending your parameters in data variable then you have to use $request['data']['username']. You cant directly access by $request['username'].

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
Input::get('username');
```

or

```
Request::get('username');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve your data like this make model and make its table

```
 $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

the above code will output the value according to date in descending                 order.
this is the best way